# Are there any ways to protect files "Date Created" metadata?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, metadata, timestamp

I've recently been going through and reorganising old photos - and came across many cases where the `Date created` metadata would not reflect the date the photos were taken (or scanned in) but instead gives the datetime at which they were last copied over from another archive directory (I assume). While my specific scenario just involves image files, I'm looking for a solution that can be applied to any filetypes.

Are there any tips/techniques to help prevent this happening in the future on Windows/Linux such as making `Date created` metadata read-only?

Also, any tips for how I could set a value for an estimated (or exact) `Date created` to correct these files which have been updated would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Date Created" is *meaningless*, it has always been just about the particular *instance* of that file. Windows doesn't allow changing it by hand, and Linux generally didn't even *have* that until recently. (And even then, only some filesystems keep the 'birth' time and there's no common API to access it. Note, "ctime" on Linux is *not* creation time.)

You'll have much more luck trying to preserve the **"Date Modified"** timestamp, which is more about the *contents* of the file. That's what most file managers show you. And most programs already preserve it by default – it's kept by Dropbox, it's kept in Zip archives, it's even transferred when downloading files *over the web*.

So my general suggestion would be to look for ways to 'lock' the *Modified* timestamp. Locking is more difficult (though likely not very necessary), but on Linux, it would be simple to write a script to at least *back up and restore* it:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
sub mtime { return (stat shift)[9]; }
print "#!/bin/sh\n";
for $file (grep {-f} glob("*")) {
    print "touch -d @".mtime($file)." '$file'\n";
}
```

(Well, it's a backup script that *generates* a restore script.)

However, you're talking about photos. I'm going to guess they're stored in JPEG, not the 'raw' formats. Most photo management tools support embedding "Exif" metadata in JPEG, and most cameras do so automatically. So for Windows, in the file explorer, you could just enable the "Date Taken" column instead of "Date Created/Modified", and it'll show you photo dates from within the JPEG files.

Comment: Thank you - I didn't realise "Date Created" is so unreliable...I thought it was something I have been doing wrong with my 'housekeeping' over the years. The script is good although I would need a solution that preserves the metadata across different operating systems

Comment: Why would it be lost across different operating systems?

Comment: I mean that my files are accessible in both windows 8.1 and Ubuntu and I'm looking for a way to ensure the modified date is protected under both environments